# Image lazy loading throws an error

Tags: javascript, html, image, lazy-loading

I have a problem with images which should load lazy. When i preferred all it
throws some error like **Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a constructor**. Here is a [example](https://codepen.io/Shuree/pen/gvpOwm)

```
window.bLazy = new new Blazy({
  success: function(element) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var parent = element.parentNode;
        parent.className = parent.className.replace(/\bloading\b/, '');
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Any advice ?

Comment: `new` keyword has been used twice

Comment: I am so sorry I've edited my question :) .

Comment: Oh I notice that. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` keyword has been used twice.